# Cuctom camera showing blur image in some deveices(HTC one ,Alcatol7040,LG D415 etc)

Tags: android, android-camera

I am following below scenario to set the camera preview size.

```
    Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
    parameters.setPreviewSize(sizes.get(0).width, sizes.get(0).height);
    camera.setParameters(parameters);
```

It is working fine in s4,s6,note devices.But some specific devices the preview size taking lowest preview sizes.

For example if the device have 5 supported preview sizes.

06-24 15:34:20.566 I/CameraVideoTestActivity(18551): startCam 0 PrevSize: Height: 720 Width: 960

06-24 15:34:20.571 I/CameraVideoTestActivity(18551): Size Index 0 Height 720 Width 960

06-24 15:34:20.571 I/CameraVideoTestActivity(18551): Size Index 1 Height 720 Width 1280

06-24 15:34:20.571 I/CameraVideoTestActivity(18551): Size Index 2 Height 480 Width 640

06-24 15:34:20.576 I/CameraVideoTestActivity(18551): Size Index 3 Height 288 Width 352

06-24 15:34:20.576 I/CameraVideoTestActivity(18551): Size Index 4 Height 240 Width 320

In some devices the camera defaultly picking the last preview size.If i print the bitmap width and height in onpicturetaken callback it is giving
width 320 height 240, then it is giving blur image.

In our case it needs to take the first supported preview size like width 960 height 720.

Answer (score 0):

There is no particular order for the sizes returned [by `getSupportedPreviewSizes()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29). Hence, your app should not be assuming that the sizes are in some particular order. You need to implement some selection algorithm to find the preview size that you want (e.g., largest in terms of area).

Comment: I written one algorithm to find supported preview sizes.It is giving some sizes but finally if i set that size also,it is taking the least size.It is not taking the correct size in all above mentioned devices it is taking the least size.

Comment: Is there any way to force to take this size programatically

Comment: @KomalCanny: While I have seen plenty of buggy camera implementations, I have yet to see any where `setPreviewSize()` does not use the size that you request, so long as that size is one of the sizes returned by `getSupportedPreviewSizes()`. There is nothing more you can do other than call `setPreviewSize()`; there is no `setPreviewSizePrettyPlease()` or `setPreviewSizeOrElse()` method on `Camera.Parameters`. Make sure that you are only calling `setPreviewSize()` once, though, and that you do not have code elsewhere that might be calling `setPreviewSize()` a second time with the wrong size.